# DocuSign optional signing

Tags: docusignapi

I need to create an envelope using DocuSign SOAP with two recipients and signature tags. In order to complete the envelope, I only need one of the recipient to sign the document. Both recipients should be in the same order but if either recipient signs the document, I want envelope status to be completed.
Is there a ways to accomplish this?

I tried using conditional fields - created separate checkbox tag(shared) and signature tag for each recipient. I applied condition to the signature tag so that it will only show if the checkbox is checked for that recipient.
When either recipient views the document, if he wants to sign the document, he will simply check the checkbox so that he will see the signature tag and sign the document.

While the other recipient views the document, he will see that the other recipient have signed the document so he will simply view the document and envelope gets completed.

It works but I think it is probably not the best solution out there. Also, it requires DocuSign account to be enabled for conditional fields.
Is there any alternative solution out there?

Comment: Are your two recipients the same people each time? If so check this out, https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/advanced-sending/using-any-signer-option

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to use the **Any Signer** option as Andrew mentions in the above comment.  With that feature you can setup a shared/group email alias that your signers can each be a member of and when requests are sent to that alias the envelope is complete as soon as the first person signs and completes.

Here's a how-to guide regarding the Any Signer option:

https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/advanced-sending/using-any-signer-option